# Replace the Text of Div without any event which is loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to update the content of of a tag which is loaded 
via ajax.

```
<li id="DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-start-hour1-01:00" title="01:00" class="dopselect-selected">01:00</li>
```

I have also tried

```
jQuery('#DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-start-hour1-01:00').text('Hellow World');
```

this is loaded with ajax i want to update it on client side. I am trying to change the 01:00 to Noon with jQuery. But this content is loaded with ajax from a file.

i have tried

```
$("body").on( "click", "#DOPSelect-DOPBSPCalendar-start-hour1-01:00", function( event ) {});
```

But this requires an event to complete is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: can you add more information on what you are trying to do? Maybe add more html or script will help.

Comment: You should be able to do so in the (callback) function which appends the `<li>`.

Comment: @LuudJacobs this content is loaded via ajax

Comment: Why don't you trigger it on `ready`.